# display username after a user loggs in in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have quotes app that lists quotes i have a login page that works fine but i want to display the username when they logged in
here is my login method

```
function logIn() {
    var URL = 'http://localhost:8080/RESTful/rest/crazyquotes/login';
    console.log('logInUser');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: URL,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formToJSONLogin(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            window.location.replace('http://localhost:8080/RESTful/quotes.html');
            window.alert(showuser());
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            window.alert('User does not exit');
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

my method to get the username

```
function getusername() {
    var user = JSON.stringify({
        'username': $('#loginuser').val()
        });
    var obj = JSON.parse(user);
    return obj.username;

}
```

I want to display the username here

```
<div class="bs-Signout">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" id="currentlogged" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">I want to display the username here<span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/RESTful/index.html">Sign out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Edit: I have the method but how do i call it after success so it displays in the quotes.html?

```
function logIn() {
    var URL = 'http://localhost:8080/RESTful/rest/crazyquotes/login';
    console.log('logInUser');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: URL,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formToJSONLogin(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            window.location.replace('http://localhost:8080/RESTful/quotes.html');
             getusername();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            window.alert('User does not exit');
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you stringifying an object only to parse is on the very next line? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: why do you need jQuery for this when you do an immediate redirect on login success and thus have access to user in a server session

Comment: is there any jquery method that i can use ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would just simply add username inside before  by:

```
$('username').before('.caret');
```

Comment: you have invalid syntax and why would you be setting an attribute?